# Why isn't my custom font working properly on popular browsers?

Tags: html, css, font-face, web-frontend, custom-font

I Downloaded all the formats of this two fonts, the humane one works on mozilla and chrome but not on safari and the Sharp Grotesk font doesn't work in none of the most popular browsers.

In my CSS I have :

```
:root {
  /*color palette*/
  --color-primario: #305ae2;
  --color-secundario-oscuro: #000111;
  --color-secundario-claro: #f7f7f7;

  /*fonts*/
  --fuente-titulos: "Humane", sans-serif;
  --fuente-cuerpo: "Sharp", sans-serif;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Sharp", sans-serif;
  src: url("../fonts/SharpGrotesk-Medium20.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("../fonts/SharpGrotesk-Medium20.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../fonts/SharpGrotesk-Medium20.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("../fonts/SharpGrotesk-Medium20.svg") format("svg"),
    url("../fonts/SharpGrotesk-Medium20.eot") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("../fonts/SharpGrotesk-Medium20.otf") format("opentype");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Sharp", sans-serif;
  src: url("../fonts/SharpGrotesk-Book20.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("../fonts/SharpGrotesk-Book20.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../fonts/SharpGrotesk-Book20.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("../fonts/SharpGrotesk-Book20.svg") format("svg"),
    url("../fonts/SharpGrotesk-Book20.eot") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("../fonts/SharpGrotesk-Book20.otf") format("opentype");
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Humane", sans-serif;
  src: url("../fonts/Humane-Bold.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("../fonts/Humane-Bold.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../fonts/Humane-Bold.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("../fonts/Humane-Bold.svg") format("svg"),
    url("../fonts/Humane-Bold.eot") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("../fonts/Humane-Bold.otf") format("opentype");
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Humane", sans-serif;
  src: url("../fonts/Humane-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("../fonts/Humane-Regular.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../fonts/Humane-Regular.otf") format("truetype"),
    url("../fonts/Humane-Regular.svg") format("svg"),
    url("../fonts/Humane-Regular.eot") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("../fonts/Humane-Regular.otf") format("opentype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  font-family: var(--fuente-titulos) !important;
  font-family: "Humane", sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1;
}

p {
  font-family: "Sharp", sans-serif !important;
}

p,
a,
h6 {
  font-family: var(--fuente-cuerpo) !important;
  font-family: "Sharp", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

I wanted to make an compatible and good looking website with custom fonts that didn't come to reality with one font half working and and other one that doesn't work at all.

I will appreciate if someone could give me a solution to this problem since I have tried by all possible means (even gpt) and I have not been able to fix it.

Comment: Can you expand on "i downloaded"? Did you download the fonts to the hard drive on your local machine? or you downloaded them to the server that is hosting the web page? For other people to be able to see and use your custom fonts, they will also need the fonts - which generally means they will have to be served remotely somehow, just like the web page (unless the font is such a common one that you can be sure that most users will already have it on their computer)

Comment: I downloaded on my virtual machine, I haven't publish this work yet.

Comment: Look in the Chrome network tab for errors. You can either run a local webserver to server files over HTTP, or you can try replacing the paths with `file://`, but be aware that won't work anywhere but on your own computer.